# Batch inserts in JDBC - how much slower will a single transaction be?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I just found out that JDBC's addBatch operation, if given "INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)" will create something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (1, "a"); 
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (2, "b");
...
END TRANSACTION
```

Compared to a statement like this: `"INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (1, "a"), (2, "b"), .. "`, how much slower will a massive transaction be? Will the difference in I/O matter significantly?

Comment: I thought batching was about eliminating network roundtrips and latency.  Obviously it'll make a big difference to send one batch of N operations than doing N operations with a roundtrip each.

Answer (score 1):

PgJDBC batching is generally not as fast as a multi-valued `INSERT`, but it *is* more convenient.

By far the most efficient option is to use the `COPY` command via [PgJDBC's support for `COPY`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html).

A second option is to open a transaction, do batches of multi-valued inserts of (say) 10 rows per insert, followed by a set of single-row inserts to make up the difference and then a commit.

PgJDBC batching should not be significantly faster than opening a transaction, preparing a statement, looping over the data sending each row with the prepared statement, then doing an explicit commit. I don't *think* that it currently has multiple statements in-flight at once in a batch, but I'm not sure of that and if it does that would make batches significantly faster when network latency is a factor.

I'd suggest testing it out and getting a practical idea of the impact.

Answer (score 0):

Batch processing is usually faster then otherwise.

Below are several cases to give you an idea, assuming this is the same connection:

1. Auto-commit is ON. DB writes TX log. Batch is faster.
2. Auto-commit is ON. DB does not write TX log. Same speed, networking issues might cause batch be faster.
3. Auto-commit is OFF. DB writes TX log. Same in (2)
4. Auto-commit is OFF. DB does not write log. Same in (2).

Since usually queries are executed in TX with logging and networking is a bottleneck, batch processing is usually faster. For the same reason ORM frameworks provide a facility to execute queries in a batch mode.